# default.realm file is automatically generated

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have specified a Relam file "NoteData.realm" in Appdelegate. The file works fine and everything is OK. But default.realm file is created unconditionally.

I do not want the default.realm file to be created.

What should I do?

Comment: can you post your code for creating realm DB ?

Comment: This is not a problem with the code. As soon as the app is launched, the realm will generate a default.realm file without the realm generating code. Do you know how to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can stop the creation of the file, but you can definitely replace it. This is how I use a pre-populated `Realm` file instead of the empty `default.realm`. If you are storing your `Realm` file in a different location, you can just change the `path` variable.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default", ofType: "realm")

    if let defaultPath = defaultPath, let bundledPath = path {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: bundledPath, toPath: defaultPath)
        } catch {
            print("Error copying pre-populated Realm \(error)")
        }
    }
    _ = try! Realm()
    return true
}
```